# the expected norm of matrices with sub-gaussian entries

Tags: probability, statistics

It is the exercise 4.4.6 in the book High-dimension-probability, https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf
Given the theorem that $$Prob\{||A||>CK(\sqrt m + \sqrt n +t)\} \leq 2exp(-t^2)\\for~t > 0$$
In results like this, C and c will always denote some positive absolute constants

Prove that $$E||A|| \leq CK(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)$$
The book gives the hint that it can be solved directly by using the theorem above.
So I tried to calculate out the expection of operator norm of A:$$E||A||=\int_0^{CK(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)}P(||A||>a)da + \int_{CK(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)}^\infty P(||A||>a)da\\ \leq \int_0^{CK(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)}P(||A||>a)da + \int_0^\infty 2exp(-t^2)dt \\ = \int_0^{CK(\sqrt m + \sqrt n)}P(||A||>t)dt + \sqrt \pi$$

And I get stuck here. It seems not a right direction because I don't know the structure when t is smaller than 0.

Hint or helpful material are welcome.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. Questions posed as:-"This is an exercise: solve it for me" are poorly received from other members. I you want to help other members help you, provide context for your question: for example, what did you tried to solve it? And where you get stuck?

Comment: A complete qustion would include: 1. the book's mention that "
In results like this, C and c will always denote some positive absolute constants", and 2. your own attempts. Where are they?

Comment: changes have been made. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to show that, if $X\geqslant0$ almost surely and $$P(X\geqslant c+x)\leqslant2e^{-x^2}$$ for some nonnegative $c$, for every nonnegative $x$, then $E(X)\leqslant c$ (simply use $X=\|A\|/CK$ and $c=\sqrt m+\sqrt n$). Without further properties of $X$, this does not hold. But one has $$E(X)=\int_0^\infty P(X\geqslant x)dx\leqslant\int_0^cdx+\int_0^\infty P(X\geqslant c+x)dx$$ which leads to $$E(X)\leqslant c+\int_0^\infty 2e^{-x^2}dx=c+\sqrt\pi$$ One can refine this slightly, replacing the bound $2e^{-x^2}$ by $$\min\{1,2e^{-x^2}\}$$ but this will not yield $E(X)\leqslant c$, only $E(X)\leqslant c+$some other absolute constant.

However, if $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then $$\sqrt m+\sqrt n\geqslant2>\sqrt\pi$$ hence, in the original notations, one gets $$E(\|A\|)\leqslant C'K(\sqrt m+\sqrt n)$$ with $$C'=2C$$ In view of the book's mention that "In results like this, C and c will always denote some positive absolute constants" (whose exact values may vary from line to line, as one usually adds), this last inequality might be what the authors had in mind.

Comment: Thanks. It seems clear now when constant C is clarified.